# What is the difference between enc_out_dim and latent_dim in variational autoencoders

Tags: python, pytorch, autoencoder

I am reading [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/variational-autoencoder-demystified-with-pytorch-implementation-3a06bee395ed) article and have question concerning dimensions of latent space and enc_out_dim

```
class VAE(pl.LightningModule):



 def __init__(self, enc_out_dim=512, latent_dim=256, input_height=32):
        super().__init__()

        self.save_hyperparameters()

        # encoder, decoder
        self.encoder = resnet18_encoder(False, False)
        self.decoder = resnet18_decoder(
            latent_dim=latent_dim,
            input_height=input_height,
            first_conv=False,
            maxpool1=False
        )

        # distribution parameters
        self.fc_mu = nn.Linear(enc_out_dim, latent_dim)
        self.fc_var = nn.Linear(enc_out_dim, latent_dim)

        # for the gaussian likelihood
        self.log_scale = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0.0]))
```

Can you explain here what is difference between enc_out_dim and latent_dim? I want to implement variational autoencoder with tree_lstm as encoder and I am not sure how give values enc_out_dim and latent_dim.

Comment: In AE, Encoder output, Decoder input is usually called latent embedding, and its dimension is `latent_dim`. this author adds fc layer after his encoder, and then he calls the dimension of encoder output `enc_out_dim`. In fact, encoder + fc is the   the Encoder in AE.

Comment: @TianshuWang If we have inputs only images, then transposed convolutions will be applied to enc_out_dim?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite catch what you mean. I'm not familiar with CV.